# Code to conditionally format (color fill) selected cells based on text

Tags: excel, vba

I have created this code to change the font of cells that end with the Letter S, and it works great.  I just need to change it so that instead of changing the font, it fills the cells with the color red.  A bonus would be how to conditionally format it to do a vertical left to right color fill.  Anyways, here's my code that works to change the font color:

```
Sub HighlightS()

    ' HighlightS Macro

    Dim rStart As Range
    Set rStart = Selection

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="S", _

    TextOperator:=xlEndsWith

    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .Color = vbRed
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Not effective", _
                                   TextOperator:=xlContains

    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .Color = vbRed
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to use the macro recorder, it should give you what you need, or the very least a starting point.

Comment: `Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed`

Comment: Thank you both.  I never actually used the macro recorder.  It's much easier than manually figuring out code.  Also, what u said worked Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[self-answered by Sabatino](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56588138/3)

```
Sub SFillRed()

    ' Highlights Macro
    Dim rStart As Range
    Set rStart = Selection

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="S", _
                                   TextOperator:=xlEndsWith
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Not effective", _
                                   TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End Sub
```